# Redirect based on selected checkbox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect, checkbox

I have several checkboxes in a switch statement like the one below:

```
function whatsChecked(obj) {
    var indx = obj.id.substring(obj.id.length-1, obj.id.length);
    switch ( indx ) {
        case '9':
            if (document.sport.soccer_9.checked) {
                //window.open.href = "../google.com";;
                window.open("../google.com"); 
            } 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use a continue button to determine which checkbox was clicked and redirect me to the correct page (instead of giving each checkbox it's own onclick event)?

Answer (score 1):

Also at http://jsfiddle.net/amelvin/YkFza/

In this example all the change events of the checkboxes register themselves, and if you check one of the boxes the value of the checkbox is alerted out.  If you change the `alert(this.value)` to `location.href(this.value)` you will have your redirect.

```
<form>
Google: <input type="checkbox" name="Google" value="http://google.com" />
Yahoo: <input type="checkbox" name="Yahoo" value="http://yahoo.com" />
</form>  

<script>
function AddHandlers(f)
{
    var change_handler = new Function("alert(this.value)");

    for (var i=0; i<f.elements.length; i++)
     {
        var e = f.elements[i];
         e.onchange = change_handler;    
     }
}

AddHandlers(document.forms[0]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a variable, that switches depending on which checkbox is checked. (Perhaps an int value)

And then, when you click 'continue' you can say `If (click == 1) { window.open(www.google.com") }` or something to that effect. Probably not the most elegant solution, but it certainly should work.

Comment: how would that work with each checkbox going to a different link? for example checkbox 1 goes to google and checkbox 2 goes to yahoo, etc.

Comment: If every checkbox has a different `int` value, then you can check it through an `if` or `switch` statement. But go with @amelvin's answer. His code is much more fluid and versatile because my code relies on two values essentially, and his only relies on one. (The value value)